# Is it possible to target a specific tablesorter column by class when using the filter widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the @Mottie branch of tablesorter.js

I have 5-10 small tables on a page and would like to use an external filter to filter all of them at once, but only on one column.  The docs mention:

```
      // filters to exclude, per column
      filter_excludeFilter : {},
```

It requires zero-based indexing to select columns for exclusion; however, the column # I am selecting varies from table to table.  I was hoping to just target a column by header class, because I can apply a class to it.  Relevant code:

```
HTML: <input type="search" class="search" placeholder="filter..." /></div>

js:
      var $table = $(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
      widgets: ["filter"],
      widgetOptions: {
          filter_external: '.search',
          filter_defaultFilter: { '.salesinitials': '~{q}', },
          filter_functions: { '.salesinitials': true },
          filter_columnFilters: false
      }
  });

  $("th > div.tablesorter-header-inner:contains('Sales Initials')")
   .parent().addClass("salesinitials");
```

Is there some other way to target just one column for filtering on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`filter_excludeFilter` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-exclude-filter) does allow you to use a jQuery selector in place of a column index.

But, I think the solution you need is to bind all the tables to one filter input using the [filter bindSearch function](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#function-bindsearch):

```
var $filter = $('.single-filter-input');
$('.all-tables').each(function(table) {
  // table - table DOM element (or jQuery object) of table.
  // $el - jQuery object of one or more input (search) elements to bind.
  // false - boolean flag to force a new search.
  $.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch(table, $filter, false);
});
```